# gstreamer: No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wav' / no suitable plugins found

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, gstreamer

I develop a Kivy Python application. It should have a sound effect.
In Kivy it is simple as:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
...
    def btn(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load("images/crunch.ogg")
        if sound:
            sound.play()
```

When this piece of code runs I got:

```
[WARNING] [AudioGstplayer] b"No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wav'."
[ERROR  ] [AudioGstplayer] b'Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.'
[ERROR  ] [AudioGstplayer] b'Internal data stream error.'
```

I have learned that Kivy uses GStreamer. So I tried to play sound using its basic utility in terminal:

```
(base) $ gst-play-1.0 -v PycharmProjects/dima_kivy/images/crunch.wav
Press 'k' to see a list of keyboard shortcuts.
Now playing /home/slv/PycharmProjects/dima_kivy/images/crunch.wav
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = file:///home/slv/PycharmProjects/dima_kivy/images/crunch.wav
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstFileSrc\)\ source"
/GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-wav
WARNING No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wav'.
WARNING debug information: gsturidecodebin.c(921): unknown_type_cb (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0
ERROR Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in. for file:///home/slv/PycharmProjects/dima_kivy/images/crunch.wav
ERROR debug information: gsturidecodebin.c(988): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
gstdecodebin2.c(4679): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: WAV (audio/x-wav)
```

It seems that the problem is not about Kivy.
I googled that for someone installing helps - so did I:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

Running this "install all" command changed nothing. Behavior keeps the same.
I guess that there is some misconfiguration but I do not have even a clue where to find(

Please, help!

my system: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

gst-inspect-1.0 output:

```
(base) slv@slv-ubuntu-comp:~$ gst-inspect-1.0 audio/x-wav
Factory Details:
  Rank                     primary (256)
  Name                     audio/x-wav
  Caps                     audio/x-wav
  Extensions               wav

Plugin Details:
  Name                     typefindfunctions
  Description              default typefind functions
  Filename                 /home/slv/miniconda3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgsttypefindfunctions.so
  Version                  1.14.5
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-base
  Source release date      2019-05-29
  Binary package           GStreamer Base Plug-ins source release
  Origin URL               Unknown package origin
```

```
(base) slv@slv-ubuntu-comp:~$ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep wav
typefindfunctions: application/x-shockwave-flash: swf, swfl
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wav: wav
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack: wv, wvp
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack-correction: wvc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found that when I installed using conda:

```
conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

I accidentally made it also in **base** conda environment and it resulted that system path to standard Ubuntu installation of gstreamer was overwritten.
So i fixed my **base** conda environment by removing kivy in that environment.
Now command *gst-play-1.0 ~/PycharmProjects/dima_kivy/images/crunch.wav* works well and produces sound as expected in the base environment.

As for error "gstreamer: No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wav' / no suitable plugins found" in my development environment, I have made a step forward by installing **good** plugins from conda-forge in my development environment as follows:

```
conda install gst-plugins-good -c conda-forge
```

It fixes the mentioned in the title error, but still no sound comes from my PC.
I will ask the stackoverflow community another question for this new problem.

Comment: Hello, do you have a follow up on this problem ?
I have had the same issue and solved it in a similar fashion but I also have no audio.

I do have an error log though:
`GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:18:37.374: gst event set seqnum: assertion 'seqnum != GST SEQNUM INVALID' failed`

But I'm guessing solving this will not solve my problem :-)